# What is the average waiting time for these processes with SJF scheduling algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

How to find the average waiting time for a shortest job first scheduling algorithm? This algorithm is non-preemptive.

Processes - Arrival Time - Burst Time

P1 ----------------- 0.0 ------------- 8 -------

P2 ----------------- 0.4 ------------- 4 -------

P3 ----------------- 1.0 ------------- 1 -------

**Thought process**

At 0, P1 enters the queue and enters the CPU.

At 0.4, P2 enters the queue, but since this is non-preemptive, P1 still executes.

At 1.0, P3 enters the queue, but P1 still executes

At 8.0, P1 finishes and leaves the CPU. P3 now enters the CPU because it has a shorter burst time.

At 9.0, P3 finishes and leaves the CPU. P2 enters the CPU.

At 13.0, P2 finishes and leaves the CPU.

So to calculate the waiting time is to subtract the time the process starts executing by the arrival time. So the average waiting time should be...

(0 + (8 - 1) + (9 - 0.4) = 15.6 / 3 = **5.2**

However, according to my professor, that's incorrect.

I know I could ask my professor, which I did, but he is currently away and I just thought to ask stackoverflow what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!